# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded AngularJS MEAN STACK

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am having a Maximum call stack error on AngularJS
Here is my code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><!--ANGULAR 1.5.8 -->
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="./NodeJS/node_modules/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./angular/css/angular-material.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./angular/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.2.1/sweetalert2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/components/accordion.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./angular/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./angular/css/main.css">

<base href="/">
</head>



<body ng-app="main">

<div ng-view>

</div>




<!--<script src="./js/angular.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-aria.js"></script>
<!--<script src="./js/angular-route.js"></script>-->
<script src="./js/ngStorage.js"></script>
<!--<script src="./js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>   
<script src="./js/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/angular-messages.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="./js/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.2.1/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="./NodeJS/node_modules/file-saver/FileSaver.js"></script>-->
<script src="./js/app.js"></script>




<script src="./service/loginService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/cvMyProfileService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/cvNameService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/cvPersonalInfoService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/cvPersonalStatementService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/cvExperienceService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/cvEducationService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/cvSkillService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/cvGeneratorService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/genauthkeyService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/registerService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/studentregService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/skillExampleService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/psExampleService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/cvedit/cvEditService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/cvedit/cvEditSkillService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/cvedit/cvEditExperienceService.js"></script>
<script src="./service/cvedit/cvEditEducationService.js"></script>




<script src="./controller/loginController.js"></script>
<script src="./controller/genauthkeyController.js"></script>
<script src="./controller/portalController.js"></script>
<script src="./controller/registerController.js"></script>
<script src="./controller/studentregController.js"></script>
<script src="./controller/skillExampleController.js"></script>
<script src="./controller/psExampleController.js"></script>
<script src="./controller/editcvController.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="./directive/nospaceallowed.js"></script>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/components/accordion.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/font-awesome.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Server

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');  
var morgan = require('morgan');  
var passport = require('passport');
var config = require('./config/main')
var User = require('./app/models/users');    
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');  
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var officegen = require('officegen');
var async = require('async');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var path = require('path');

//Routes
var tokenAuthRoute = require('./routes/tokenAuth');
var authkeyRoute = require('./routes/generatekey');
var registerRoute = require('./routes/register');
var cvRoute = require('./routes/cvsave');
var cvExperienceRoute = require('./routes/cvExperience');
var cvEducationRoute = require('./routes/cvEducation');
var cvSkillRoute = require('./routes/cvSkill');
var cvPSERoute = require('./routes/cvPSE');
var cvEditRoute = require('./routes/cvEdit');




var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Use body-parser to get POST requests for API use
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));  
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  next();
});



// Log requests to console
app.use(morgan('dev'));  

// Initialize passport for use
app.use(passport.initialize());  

// Bring in defined Passport Strategy
require('./config/passport')(passport);  


mongoose.connect(config.database);

app.options('*', cors());
app.use(cors());



app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/assets/js'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/assets/css'));
app.use('/controller', express.static(__dirname + '/assets/controller'));
app.use('/service', express.static(__dirname + '/assets/service'));
app.use('/directive', express.static(__dirname + '/assets/directive'));

// Set url for API group routes
app.use(tokenAuthRoute);  
app.use(authkeyRoute);
app.use(registerRoute);
app.use(cvRoute);
app.use(cvExperienceRoute);
app.use(cvEducationRoute);
app.use(cvSkillRoute);
app.use(cvPSERoute);
app.use(cvEditRoute);

// app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
//     // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
//   res.sendFile(path.resolve('../index.html'));
// });

app.use(function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root : '../'})
});

app.listen(PORT, function(req, res){
    console.log('Server started at port ' + PORT);
});
```

ngRoute

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider){

  $routeProvider
    .when("/",{
      templateUrl : "./angular/templates/frontp.htm",
      controller : "LoginController"
    })
    .when("/portal",{
      templateUrl: "./angular/templates/portal.htm",
      controller: "LoginController"
    })
    .when("/gak",{
      templateUrl: "./angular/templates/genauthkey.htm",
      controller: "GenAuthkeyController"
    })
    .when("/register",{
        templateUrl: "./angular/templates/register.htm",
        controller: "StudentRegController"
    })
    .when("/addskillexample", {
        templateUrl: "./angular/templates/skillExample.htm",
        controller: "SkillExampleController"
    })
    .when("/addpsexample", {
        templateUrl: "./angular/templates/psExample.htm",
        controller: "PSExampleController"
    })
    .when("/portal/cvedit", {
      templateUrl: "./angular/templates/editcv.htm",
      controller: "EditCVController"
    })
  .otherwise({
    templateUrl : "./angular/templates/error404.htm"
  });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

So i got this problem when i started to get rid of the Hashtag symbol on url (www.examplelink.com/#/)
So i got rid of the hashtag thing by setting up the **$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);** and the  its all working but the problem is when i reload the page, it goes 404, for example,

- login with username and password
- i will be redirected to /portal
- i try to refresh/press F5, it will go to 404 page not found

so i did a research on this and found an answer. So basically im serving the index.html file and handling the route by AngularJS, so i copied some code and have my express server serve the index.html file, but the routes are still provided ng ngRoute of AngularJS

The code that i copied was

```
app.use(function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root : '../'})
});
```

Then i migrated the css, js, controller, services and directive to my NodeJS folder then i statically defined them by using express static. Because before, those files are in my AngularJS folder.

So after i migrated all of them, fixing the location path, now i am having this error of maximum call stack.

[image]

Can anyone teach me how to fix this? i've saw some posts here in SO but no luck.

Thanks guys!

Comment: this is definitely recursing at invokeLinkFn function (please investigate around angular.js:10252 lines)

Comment: it's not showing anything

Comment: 1.) First Place make sure you comment out your html properly I see few glitches there.
2.) maximum call stack exceeded is related something with getter and setter inside angular.js code. In your whole app code there is a place where your property and return from property have same names.
3.) Tip for node.js require :- Its better use const instead of var for adding modules into node.js